# How to solve this recurrence relation of x and g?

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$x_{t+1}=x_t-2g_t\\
g_t=0.9g_{t-1}+0.2x_t\\
 g_{-1}=0\\$$
Suppose $x_0$ will be given. How to solve this recurrence relation? Write it as $s_t=\begin{bmatrix}
x_t\\x_{t-1}\end{bmatrix}, s_{t+1}=Ms_t$, where M is a 2x2 matrix?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Maybe calculate the first few values of each sequence and see if you can identify a pattern

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations:

\begin{eqnarray*}
x_{t+1}&=&x_t-2g_t = x_t-2[0.2x_t-0.9]g_{t-1} = (0.6)x_t+(-1.8)g_{t-1}\\
g_t &=& (0.2)x_t+(0.9)g_{t-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{t+1}\\
g_t
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.6 & -1.8\\
0.2 & 0.9
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_t\\
g_{t-1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.6 & -1.8\\
0.2 & 0.9
\end{bmatrix}^2
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{t-1}\\
g_{t-2}
\end{bmatrix}
=\cdots =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.6 & -1.8\\
0.2 & 0.9
\end{bmatrix}^t
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
g_0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.6 & -1.8\\
0.2 & 0.9
\end{bmatrix}^{t+1}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\
g_{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.6 & -1.8\\
0.2 & 0.9
\end{bmatrix}^{t+1}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and good old Wolfram Alpha gives 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{500}\\
g_{499}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.6 & -1.8\\
0.2 & 0.9
\end{bmatrix}^{500}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
=
x_0
\begin{bmatrix}
-3.7\times 10^{-12}\\
4.1\times 10^{-13}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The $t=5000$ values of $x$ and $g$ are of the order of $10^{-115}$ and the $t=10000$ values are like $10^{-229}$ so it looks like both $x$ and $g$ converge to zero. There is a theorem about $A^n\to 0$ for loose conditions on a matrix $A$ but I can't find it easily. One can see easily that $\det(A^n)=(\det A)^n = (0.9)^n$ so the determinant of our coefficient matrix converges to zero.

Edit: OK, here is the result: If the spectral radius of a matrix $A$ is less than 1 then $A^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. The eigenvalues of our matrix are $\frac{1}{20}(15\pm i\sqrt{135})$ which have norm $0.9<1$ so our matrix converges to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence can be written as

$$
\cases{
x_{k+1}= x_k-2g_k\\
g_{k+1}= \frac{1}{2} x_k-\frac{1}{5} g_k}
$$

or also as

$$
\phi_{k+1}=M\phi_k
$$

with $M = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -2 \\
 \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$ 
and $\phi_k = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x_k \\
 g_k \\
\end{array}\right)$

Now

$M = T \Lambda T^{-1}$ with

$$\Lambda = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{20} \left(15+3 i \sqrt{15}\right) & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{20} \left(15-3 i \sqrt{15}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \rho e^{i\theta} & 0 \\
 0 & \rho e^{-i\theta} \\
\end{array}
\right)\\  T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{4} \left(5+3 i \sqrt{15}\right) & \frac{1}{4} \left(5-3 i \sqrt{15}\right) \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

then, from $\phi_{k+1}=T\Lambda T^{-1}\phi_k$ we have $T^{-1} \phi_{k+1}= \Lambda T^{-1}\phi_k$ and now calling $\eta_k = T^{-1}\phi_k$ we follow with

$$
\eta_{k+1}=\Lambda \eta_k \Rightarrow \eta_k = \Lambda^k\eta_0
$$

and

$$
\eta_k = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \rho^k e^{i k\theta} & 0 \\
 0 & \rho^k e^{-ik\theta} \\
\end{array}
\right)\eta_0
$$

Here $\rho = \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} < 1$ so the $\eta_k$ sequence converges to zero with $k$.

Comment: I like the use of diagonalization and how it illustrates why the eigenvalues must be less than one in magnitude for convergence of the matrix to zero. I did notice that your initial condition is $\phi_0=(x_0,g_0)$. Strictly speaking, the initial condition is $(x_0,g_{-1})^t=(x_0,0)^t$. In your setup, you would need to separately find $g_0$ and then proceed with iterating from $\phi_0=(x_0,g_0)$, but that is easily enough done: $g_0=0.2x_0$. :)

Comment: And I think $\rho=|\frac{1}{20}(15\pm 3i\sqrt{15})|=0.9$.

Comment: Sorry! One last comment: you cannot get $g_0$ from the recurrence equations as you have rearranged them.

Comment: We need two initial conditions and only one was furnished. Only $g_{-1}$ was given, We need as well an initial condition for $x_k$.

Comment: $x_0$ was assumed given :)

Comment: So $g_0 = 0.2x_0$ and then we have $\phi_0=(x_0,g_0)$